# $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+xy+1=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Solve the following differential equation by the form of homogeneous equation. Letting $y=vx$

The equation:
$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+xy+1=0$
I can’t separate variables

My solution steps are:
$x^2(v+x \frac{dv}{dx})+x^2v+1=0$
$(v+x \frac{dv}{dx})+v=\frac{-1}{x^2}$

$2v+x \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-1}{x^2}$

**How to separate variables x and v?**

Comment: Your equation is not homogeneous to start with. This method does not lead to a separable equation if the original one is not homogeneous. Your equation is actually linear for $y(x)$, so you can just multiply by the integrating factor.

Comment: I know that but the book added it under homogeneous questions

Comment: You solve a problem by thinking about the problem. Where the problem comes from may or may not be useful information.

Comment: @AnwarIsied Then your book is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, let $v = xy$ such that $\frac{dv}{dx} = y + x\frac{dy}{dx}$

$x^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + xy = x\frac{dv}{dx}$ and so $x^2\frac{dy}{dx} + xy + 1 = x\frac{dv}{dx} + 1 = 0$

You can solve $x\frac{dv}{dx} = -1$ by seperating.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the proposed DE by $x$ in order to obtain
\begin{align*}
x^{2}y' + xy + 1 = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow xy' + y = -\frac{1}{x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (xy)' = -\frac{1}{x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow xy = -\ln|x| + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = -\frac{\ln|x|}{x} + \frac{k}{x}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !